# FindFit returns a weird nrnum

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

again!

I am trying to fit a list of data points with Mathematica. The problem is that it gives me an error that the function is complex when it tries to fit even though I made the assumption that all parameters are Reals and no imaginary unit is in the function. What makes me believe it's about me not knowing Mathematica enough is that the imaginary term that it says it gets when evaluating the function is what should be considered a perfect zero: 2.975219565012465*10^-753 I. But where did it come from?

And now the code:

```
FindFit[Table[{X[[i]], weight[[i]]}, {i, Length[weight]}], {allFunc[x,
a, b, c, d, e, f, g], {a \[Element] Reals, b \[Element] Reals, 
x \[Element] Reals, c \[Element] Reals, d \[Element] Reals, 
e \[Element] Reals, f \[Element] Reals, g \[Element] Reals}}, {{a, 
10.42}, {b, -0.05435}, {c, 7.59}, {d, 3.986}, {e, 88.19}, {f, 
6.958}, {g, 104500}}, x]
```

While that allFunc is:

```
crystalBall[x_, \[Alpha]_, n_, \[Mu]_, \[Sigma]_, Norma_] :=
If[(x - \[Mu])/\[Sigma] > -\[Alpha],
Norma*Exp[-((x - \[Mu])^2/(2 \[Alpha]^2))],
Norma*(n/Abs[\[Alpha]])^
n Exp[-(Abs[\[Alpha]]^2/2)] (n/Abs[\[Alpha]] - Abs[\[Alpha]] - (
 x - \[Mu])/\[Sigma])^-n];
allFunc[x_, const_, slope_, alpha_, en_, miu_, sigma_, norm_] := 
Exp[const + slope*x] + crystalBall[x, alpha, en, miu, sigma, norm];
```

Sorry about the aspect of the code.
The error I get is:

> FindFit::nrnum: The function value 1.74493*10^14+2.975219565012465*10^-753 I is not a real number at {a,b,c,d,e,f,g} = {13.3122,0.0104586,-58.8739,3.986,87.764,6.958,104500.}. >>

I've plotted the function with those arguments in my fit range and no complex warning appeared. I also looked for a solution on the internet but I only get questions from people who wanted to do a complex fit, which I don't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

wrap your function in Re[] or Chop[]